# Android html file not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, assets

I have a folder **assets** in app directory with error.html file. It has been created via File->New->Folder->Assets Folder. I would like to show this file in method

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
{
    String path = "file:///android_assets/error.html";
    view.loadUrl(path);
}
```

but I am still getting an error file not found. I tried also "file:///app/android_assets/error.html" and "file:///assets/error.html" and "file:///app/assets/error.html" but still the same result. Can somebody tell me plaes where the file really is? It drives me crazy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: use `android_asset` not `android_assets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file:///android_asset/error.html`.

Comment: Yes it works but I don't understand. folder is named assets. there is no relations between folder name and the path? Thanks.

Comment: "folder is named assets" -- yes. "there is no relations between folder name and the path?" -- assets are not files on the filesystem of the device. `android_asset` is a fake directory that points to the contents of your `assets/`. As to why they went with the singular form for `android_asset` and the plural form for `assets`/, that has been a mystery for 12 years. So, `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.